# C# reference array assignment issue

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having a little trouble reading values in from a database and assigning them to an array. It seem to work in my unit tests, but in practice some values are missing.

Here's my database code:

```
private void GetParameterValuesFromDatabase()
{
        this.parameterValues = (from DataRow r in this.database.RunCommand("select * from KST_PARAM_VALUES v join DM_PARM_NAME p on v.PARM_NAME_KEY = p.PARM_NAME_KEY").Rows
                                where (int)r["SCENARIO_KEY"] == this.scenario.ScenarioKey
                                select new DatabaseParameter
                                {
                                    ParameterValuesKey = r.Field<int>(0),
                                    ProfileType = r.Field<string>(1),
                                    ScenarioKey = r.Field<int>(2),
                                    StressEditorKey = r.Field<int>(3),
                                    StressClassKey = r.Field<int>(4),
                                    PeriodKey = r.Field<int>(5),
                                    ParameterNameKey = r.Field<int>(6),
                                    ParameterValue = r.Field<double>(7),
                                    ActiveStress = (r.Field<string>(8) == "Y") ? true : false,
                                    ParameterKey = (int)r["PARM_NUMBER"]
                                }).ToDictionary(r => r.ParameterValuesKey, r => r);
    }
```

Not having any issues with this part of my code, just showing for completeness.

```
private void LoadParameters()
{
    this.GetParameterValuesFromDatabase();

    // TODO: Assuming 9 periods for now, change to allow for variable periods
    for (int i = 1; i <= MaxNumberOfStressPeriods; i++)
    {
        this.parametersByPeriod.Add(i, this.parameterValues.Where(t => t.Value.PeriodKey == i).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value));
    }

    Log.Instance.LogMessage(LogLevel.Debug, "Created parameter dictionaries from database");

    // For every stress editor in the dictionary of stress editors
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ClassList> ed in this.stressParams)
    {
            // For every type of class selector
            foreach (ClassSelector c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassSelector)))
            {
                // For each of the classes within each class list within the editor
                for (int i = 0; i < ed.Value.ClassLists[c].Count; i++)
                {
                    string className = ed.Value.ClassLists[c][i].Name;

                // For each double array in each class
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, double[]> t in ed.Value.ClassLists[c][i].ClassVariables.EditorParameters)
                    {
                        double[] values = this.GetParameterValues(t.Key, ed.Key, className);

                        BasicStressEditorVariables.AddParameters(values, ed.Value, className, t.Key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above shows the overall LoadParameters() method.
Below we have some code that selects 9 values from the dictionary constructed from the database, ready to be added to the array.

```
 private double[] GetParameterValues(int paramKey, int editorKey, string className)
 {
     double[] values = new double[9];

     for (int i = 1; i <= MaxNumberOfStressPeriods; i++)
     {
         Dictionary<int, DatabaseParameter> temp = this.parametersByPeriod[i];

         foreach (KeyValuePair<int, DatabaseParameter> d in temp)
         {
             if (d.Value.ParameterKey == paramKey && d.Value.PeriodKey == i && d.Value.StressEditorKey == editorKey && d.Value.ProfileType == className)
             {
                 values[i - 1] = d.Value.ParameterValue;
             }
         }
     }

     return values;
 }
```

Below shows getting the destination array from the dictionary, as indexes cannot be passed by reference

```
 public static void AddParameters(double[] values, ClassList editor, string className, int paramKey)
 {
     // TODO: Maybe search all lists to eliminate the need for the class selector as a parameter
     // TODO: Will throw an exception when nothing is found. Handle it
     ParameterClass p = null; 

     foreach (ClassSelector c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassSelector)))
     {
        p = editor.ClassLists[c].FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == className);

         if (p != null)
         {
                break;
         }                
     }
     // TODO: Notify that could not be found
     if (p == null)
     {
         Log.Instance.LogMessage(LogLevel.Error, $"Unable to find class {className}");
         return;
     }

     double[] dest = p.ClassVariables.editorParameters[paramKey];

     AddParameterValues(values, ref dest);   
 }
```

And here's the AddParameterValues() method:

```
private static void AddParameterValues(double[] values, ref double[] destination)
{
    if (values.Length != destination.Length)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = values[i];
    }
}
```

Debugging shows that some values are being loaded into the destination array, but some aren't. Could anyone tell me why this is? Or if not, point me toward some material?

Thank you for your time

Comment: "some aren't" can you tell more about which ones aren't? Are this always the same indices, or does it change each time you run the code?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - Always the same indices, the same ones are filled correctly and the same ones are filled incorrectly... debugging has shown me that the correct values are entered in the array at some point, but they don't seem to persist

Comment: which fields???

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/d7ace5310f9343f79f95bee76934325c.png  http://image.prntscr.com/image/3229c09374904df984f5b4187c6aeb6c.png Here are some screenshots showing debugging. You can see one array is empty, and the other is full

Comment: Furthermore, doing `BasicStressEditorVariables.AddParameters(new double[] { 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, job.StressParameters[2], "BANK", 1);` separately after yields the correct results and the values persist... they must be being overwritten somewhere

Comment: You should not need `ref` at all.  An array is a reference type, which means the value you're passing to the function is a _reference_ to the array.  You can add/remove.update elements of the array without making the array pass-by-ref.  You only need `ref` if you're changing which array the passed-in variable refers to,

Comment: @DStanley Ah okay, I'll change that right away... I discovered that the array is being overwritten when it gets to the next iteration of the for loop. Now to work out why and how to fix it.

Comment: I worked it out guys... when I was creating the object to hold the arrays, I was assigning the same set of arrays rather than a new set. I will answer with my solution tomorrow when I get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that C# specialist but looking to following code as a C programmer

```
private double[] GetParameterValues(int paramKey, int editorKey, string className)
{
    double[] values = new double[9];
    //...    
    return values;
}
```

I would assume that the lifetime of **values** is only within the function **GetParameterValues** and the function **GetParameterValues** delivers the caller with reference to a dead variable.
What if you change the prototype to something like

```
private void GetParameterValues(ref double[] values, int paramKey, int editorKey, string className)
```

Comment: Not true - the function can return a locally created array just fine.